# jQuery fullCalendar dayClick - convert (date) to mm/dd/yy

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

I am trying to the following:

- user clicks on a specific date
- fancybox opens with data entry options
- capture the date on which the calendar was clicked
- grab that date and inject it into the `value` of a text `input`

This is my code:

```
$("a#inline").fancybox();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar(
{
    dayClick: function (date)
    {
        $('a#inline').click();
        $('.datepicker').val(date);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#data_entry" id="inline">Add Event</a>

<div style="display:none">
    <div id="data_entry">
        <form action="events/events_save" method="post" name="events_form" id="events_form">
         <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php date('m/d/Y'); ?>" class="datepicker">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am running into the following issues:

- when clicking on a date on the calendar the fancybox pops up and I get `Mon Apr 25 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` ==> I need this to be mm/dd/yy like `04/25/11`
- if right after that I close the fancybox and click on the anchor tag `"Add Event"`,  the fancybox opens but the date is populated with `Mon Apr 25 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` ==> it should actually contain today's date because of the PHP string I put in the `value` field (this is fixed only if I refresh)

Anyone have suggestions on how to solve either issue?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To format dates, run the date through fullcalendar's [formatDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/) method.  Try:

```
$('.datepicker').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, "MM/dd/yy"));
```

Comment: brilliant - thanks a lot @justkt that worked nicely -- do you have any suggestions for the other issue?

Comment: @torr - can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: sure - i trigger a fancybox for data entry using 2 methods - [a] clicking on a calendar date, or [b] clicking an anchor text. 

The anchor text is for, say, entering an event on a date that is not displayed by the calendar at that moment (eg, a date way in the future) OR if the user prefers to enter data that way.

When clicking on the anchor, I would like the date to show as today - that why there's that PHP line in the OP code above.

But if one uses **method [a]** first, and right after uses **method [b]**, the date that shows is the one from **method [b]**.

Comment: @torr - make sure to set `$('.datepicker').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate( new Date(), "MM/dd/yy"));` on clicking from the anchor.

Comment: @justkt - where exactly do i put that line - should it go as a function following `$("a#inline").fancybox();`?

Comment: @torr - in a handler on the click event for the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Perfect! This helped me out too as I could not find any documentation on how to use formatDate method...

```
alert($.fullCalendar.formatDate( calEvent.start, "yyyy-MM-dd"));
```